# Table with random number value as first cell

Tags: php

I'm working through a snippet of code. The goal is to create a program where a user can enter three values (row, col, and highlight). The user then would then click a button and it would generate a table of 100 values. The first cell must be a random number, the second would be random number + 1. I'm just not sure how to incorporate that into my code. I must use $randnumber = rand(0,100).

Here is what I have so far...

```
<table border="1">
<?
i = 0;
        while($i < 100) {
            if($i % 10 == 0) {
                echo "<tr>";
                }
            echo ("<td>".$i."</td>");
            $i++;
            }
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to start from `$randnumber`, and print numbers up to `$randnumber+100`. Try to do it.

Comment: table of 100 values?? what you mean 100 rows or 100 coloums or 10 rows and 10 colums?

Comment: 10 rows and 10 columns.

Comment: I edited my code to try to match requirements. How do I get the values to go above 99.

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
<?php $randnumber = rand(0,100); ?>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        while($i < 100) {
          if($i % 10 == 0) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
          }
          echo ("<td>".($randnumber+$i)."</td>");
          $i++;
        }
    ?>
</tr>
</table>
```